# Es posible poner un JPasswordField en vez de un JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy trabajando por consola, pero me ha gustado que me salga la ventana de login entoncoes mi pregunta es si es posible que en vez de un JOptionPane.showInputDialog me salga un JPasswordField  para que la contraseña no se vea.
Ete es mi pedazo de codigo donde me gustaria implementarlo

```
 socket = new Socket(c.gethostName(), c.getPort());
        //create printwriter for sending login to server
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
        //send user name to server
        out.println(username);
        //prompt for password        
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");
        //send password to server        
        out.println(password);
        out.flush();
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;
```

Comment: Hola. Siempre puedes hacerte una clase que derive de `JDialog` y añadirle los componentes que necesites, en vez de usar un `JOptionPane` que tiene los tipos básicos de cuadro de diálogo pero no el que tú necesitas.

Comment: no veo la opcion aunque le ponga extends jdialog y le meta el Jpasword no veo nada en ls opciones para poder hacer algo del estilo al jopcionpane

Comment: La lógica la tienes que implementar tú en el diálogo personalizado, haciendo que cuando salgas pulsando OK, guarde la clave en una variable del objeto del diálogo. Desde la clase desde la que llamas al diálogo, al terminar, compruebas y obtienes qué ha pulsado.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible utilizando un panel personalizado, te dejo a continuación un ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creamos el panel que contendrá los componentes Label y Password
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Contraseña:");
    // Definimos el largo de la casilla para la contraseña
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(15);
    // Agregamos los componentes al panel
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(passwordField);

    // Definimos el texto de las opciones para aceptar o cancelar
    String[] options = new String[]{"Aceptar", "Cancelar"};

    // Agregamos el panel y las opciones al dialogo
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Ingreso de Contraseña",
            JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[1]);

    if(option == 0) // pressing OK button
    {
        char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();
        System.out.println("Contraseña: " + new String(password));
    }else {
        System.out.println("Ingreso de contraseña cancelada");
    }
}
```